# Controller in cakephp 3 not running

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In Cakephp 3 I create a Controller "TestController" when I run the code then it shows internal error has occurred

TestController.php

```
<?php 

/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     0.2.9
 * @license   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController; // HAVE TO USE App\Controller\AppController
// use Cake\Event\Event;

class TestController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "hii";
        // if ($this->Auth->identify()) {
        //     // $this->redirect('uploads/users/'.$_REQUEST['file'])
        //     $this->redirect($_REQUEST['file'])
        // };
        //     // else $this->redirect('AdminUsers/login');
        // else {
        //     http_response_code(404);
        // }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to get it is shows =
hii
Error
An Internal Error Has Occurred
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Back

Comment: look at ./logs/error.log and paste error in your question

Comment: it's too long how can i paste it here.

Comment: Copy only the latest error message relevant to your controller

Comment: 2021-11-25 12:44:28 Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Test\index.ctp" is missing.
Request URL: /Test

Comment: During development, you should enable debug mode, then you'll get more useful error messages in your browser instead of always having to look in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Add an template file in `src/Template/Test/index.ctp` and add some HTML.

You cannot echo within the controller. CakePHP sends the variables to the View and you can access it there:

```php
// in your controller do this:
class TestController extends AppController
   public function index() {
     $message = "Hii";
     $this->set(compact('message'));
   }
}
```

Your Tempate file `src/Template/Test/index.ctp` should look like this:

```php
<?php
 echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: Thank You but still It's not running                                                                                                                  My view is                                                                                    ` <?php echo $auth_user; ?>
<img height="100%" width="100%" src="<?php echo HTTP_PATH .$auth_user; ?>"/>`                       
My Controller is                                                                                                                      `$auth_user = $_GET['file']; $auth_user = $_GET['file'];  $this>set(compact('auth_user'));`